# Разместить изображение с ссылкой на почту

Tags: html, css

В верхней части сайта находится белый так сказать квадрат с центрированным там изображением логотипом. Так вот пытаюсь разместить ссылку картинку так чтобы половина ее заходила на это фон а половина нет. Пытался вставлять и перемещать изображение на нужное место, но при изменении масштаба она съезжает.

```
   .block1 { 
    width: 100%; 
    background: white;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center; /*центрируем элемент по горизонтали */
    align-items: center; /* и вертикали */
    height: 600px;


   }



    </style> 

    </head>
    <body>
    <div <a href="/" class="block1"><img src="img/FB_avatar.jpg"height="400"
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide slide5" id="requisites">
    <div class="description">
    <a href="mailto:crew@pamparaml.pt"><img src="img/okonka.png" width="100"height="100" alt="send"></a></p>
```

вот так вот скопирую чтобы стили было видно, что у фона с лого. Я начинающий вот и не могу разобраться.

вот вверху блок белого фона в нем в центре лого центрированное и вот значок который захлдит частью на белый фон 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я бы, как минимум, начал с исправления вот этой верстки *<div <a href="/" class="block1">*

Comment: @John Johnson Вы не могли бы, хоть от руки эскиз добавить,- как вы хотите разместить две картинки относительно друг друга. А то слова можно трактовать по разному.

Comment: Ну с такой версткой не странно, что все куда то съезжает))

Comment: Для начала прогоните вашу верстку через [валидатор](https://validator.w3.org/). Конечно верстка будет ехать, половина тегов не закрыта, сам кусок кода обрывочный, сложно вообще что-то понять.

Comment: Почитайте [основы](http://htmlboss.ru/beginner-lessons/lesson3)

Answer (score 0):

Размеры используйте абсолютные, чтобы при изменении масштаба ничего не менялось, например. Если у вас родитель флекс, то ребенок центрируется свойством margin:auto. Когда у вас размеры зафиксированы, делаете иконке position: absolute, а родителю relative и свойствами top-botton-left-right устанавливаете иконку как вам нужно. Надеюсь, правильно понял, о чем вы спрашиваете)

Comment: нет, не так ты меня понял ) лого в центре это логотип который центрируется по центре блока с белым фоном . его границы это линия нарисованная. а кружочек это и есть иконка почты котрая на половину выходит за границы блока

Comment: Я все так и понял. Вот это - "Если у вас родитель флекс, то ребенок центрируется свойством margin:auto" - игнорь. Просто совет как лучше выровнять лого по центру сразу и по высоте и по ширине. К делу не относится.

Answer (score 0):

Пробуем вот так:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  height: 100vh;
}
.block .icon {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
}
.block .icon .image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
 <div class="image">
  <img src="" alt="">
 </div>
 
 <div class="icon">
  <div class="image">
   <img src="" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```